Checking if element is Visible with Playwright
My aim is to test the case when one element is hidden under the other, e.g. with z-index.
Playwright has isVisible assertion but it only checks if element has styles like visibility: "hidden" or display: "none", while in my case I need to check if user can see the element.
My only idea now is to click on the specific point and check which element was clicked, but maybe there is something out-of-the-box to make such assertion?

Maybe just a screenshot test? A more concrete example of your use case might help here.

Yes, visual comparison like https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots

One trick you could do is trying to hover on that element.
When you call the hover function, playwright will perform its actionability checks. One of those checks is element Receives Events, as in not obscured by other elements.
It's not a silver bullet but it might work in some cases.

I would say that part of this solution:
Ollin Boer Bohan's answer
might work just fine for you
One other solution is to check if your element has a z-index attribute with
toHaveCss
and compare its z-index to other elements that exists in the same div / section
Keep in mind that the default value for z-index is auto, and as of now I'm not aware that something can do this out of the box in playwright
